# Node-sass returns a Slow buffer. What is this and how to I convert it to CSS?

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am compiling a static site using node.js. I want to compile sass. I required `node-sass` and called: `a.renderSync({data:"body{h1{color:green}}"}).css`. This returned `<SlowBuffer 62 6f 64 79 20 68 31 20 7b 0a 20 20 63 6f 6c 6f 72 3a 20 67 72 65 65 6e 3b 20 7d 0a>`. What is a slowbuffer? I just want my CSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SlowBuffer has same methods like Buffer. So to get css string, just call `toString()`:

```
a.renderSync({data:"body{h1{color:green}}"}).css.toString()
```

SlowBuffer is used when the buffer operations are passed to native C++ modules instead of JS. More about SlowBuffer is on the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_slowbuffer).